# EPiServer (Optimizely) SQL: batch update of product expiry date

Tags: sql, sql-server, episerver, optimizely

I am trying to update the product expiry date using SQL.
I used these codes:

```
UPDATE [Test.EPiServer.CM11.UAT].[dbo].[CatalogEntry]
SET EndDate = '2032-12-31 16:00:00.000'
where 
Code in ('TESTB8', 'TESTB10' )
```

It changes data on SQL results but doesn't update the product on CMS. If I update the product from CMS, it changes the SQL result. Is there another linked table?

Comment: Just as a general recommendation: refrain from manipulating the DB directly. Whenever possible and feasible: use the APIs. If this doesn't permit itself, the safest approach is to restart the app once the SQL commands have completed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the changes you make to the database using SQL will not be immediately reflected in the CMS that you are using to manage your products. This could be because the CMS has its own database, or because it caches data from the database to improve performance. In order to ensure that the changes you make to the database using SQL are reflected in the CMS, you may need to clear the cache or refresh the data in the CMS. You may also need to check if there are any additional tables or views that are used by the CMS to display product information, and make sure that those tables or views are also updated with the new expiration date.